# COUNT() return 0 on certain column

Tags: sql, database

Requirements:I wanted to know how many images that each person have posted.

Therefore I create a table schema as follow.

```
Table=Person
==========
Id (PK) , Column1, Column2, LId (FK)

Table=ListMaster
============
Id (PK) , LId (Unique)

Table = ListDetail
===========
Id (PK), LId(FK), DataId(FK)

Table = Image
=========
Id (PK), Column1, Column2
```

and use a query SQL

```
SELECT  Person.Id AS PersonId,
        Person.Column1 AS PersonC1,
        Person.Column2 AS PersonC2, 
        COUNT(Image.Id) AS ImageCount
FROM Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN ListMaster ON Person.LId = ListMaster.LId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ListDetail ON ListDetail.LId = ListMaster.LId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data AS Image ON ListDetail.DataId = Image.Id
GROUP BY Person.Id,
         Person.Column1,
         Person.Column2
```

I notice some person's "ImageCount" have "0" although there are images that he have posted before.

Could you please advise me how to fix my query or tell me it is even logically possible to do what I wanted? I suspect I make a mistake regarding my table design.

```
Sample Data
=======

Table = Person

Id (PK)(bigint identity) | Column1 (nvarchar(max)) | Column2 (nvarchar(max)) | LId (FK) (bigint [null])

1  |  Test 1 C1 | Test1 C2  | 1

2  |  Test 2 C1 | Test 2 C2 | 2

3 |   Test 3 C1 | Test 3 C2  | NULL

4 |   Test 4 C1 | Test 4 C4 |  37

Table = ListMaster

Id (PK)(bigint)(identity) | LId (Unique)(bigint)

1  |  1

2  |  2

3  |  37

Table = ListDetail



  Id (PK)(bigint identity)| LId(FK)(bigint not null)| DataId(FK)(bigint not null)
1  |  1 |  1

2  |  1 |  2

3  |  2 |  3

4  |  37 | 4

Table = Image

Id (PK)(big int not null)(identity) | Column1 (nvarchar(max)) | Column2 (nvarchar(max))

1 | Location 1  | Dummy Data 1

2 | Location 2  | Dummy Data 2

3 | Location 3 |  Dummy Data 3

4 | Location 4  |  Dummy Data 4
```

I expect the COUNT(Image.Id) AS ImageCount should return

```
2
1
0
1
```

but it return

```
2
1
0
0
```

EDIT 1 : Change the table design

EDIT 2 : Add a sample data

Comment: Your query looks, ok, so probably is a data issue. Try remove `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` and add `DATA.*` so you can see your data result before group it.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have try SELECT * FROM Image and it was showing the correct data. But when I try to use COUNT() and GROUP BY, the "ImageCount" become "0".

Comment: I have also change the table design to a correct one.

Comment: Note that `COUNT(expr)` only counts rows where `expr` is not null. If any of your `Image.Id`s are null (which would be weird for an ID but not impossible), they won't be counted.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, I have prevent such case by using **not null** in the `Image.Id` column. In fact, I have use  *identity* on `Image.Id` column which is "big int not null"

Comment: Yes, but as you are doing a LEFT OUTER join to Image, then if there's no Image linked to that Person through the joins you're doing, you'll still get a NULL in Image.id. For example, if your `ListDetail` has a `DataId` that's not present in `Image.Id`, then your results will have a NULL `Image.Id`. That's how OUTER JOINs work. Pick a single person you *think* should have an Image but where your COUNT is zero, and work through your joins from the Person to the Data table, and see which one is actually missing.

Comment: We need column names for your sample data, and data types for *all* your columns, please.

Comment: You appear to be changing the name of the last table from "image" to "data". I suspect this is just because you're trying to simplify the schema for purposes of this post, but ...

Comment: As written, there's no reason to include ListMaster in the query. You could eliminate it and just "join ListDetail on ListDetail.Lid=person.Lid".

Comment: @Jay , Yes, I have simplify the schema for the purpose of this post. After removing `ListMaster` as you suggested, the query now work as it should. Still I am interested in why it work after removing `ListMaster` for future references. Could you please tell me? According to what I understand, even if I put `ListMaster`, the query should still work despite the slow performance due to extra `JOIN` statement.

Comment: There is no reason; given your data and your query, your results should be as you expect them, from what I can see. Therefore there's something else going on that's not clear to us.

Comment: @SunMaungOo I suspect something important has been lost in your simplification for the post. If removing that join makes it work, then the problem must involve that join.

Comment: @jay, I can reproduce an error.

Consider ImagePathListMaster as ListMaster,
ImagePathListDetail  as ListDetail,
ImagePath as Image

**Incorrect one**

`SELECT COUNT(ImagePath.Id) AS ImageCount
FROM Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN ImagePathListMaster AS ImagePathListMaster ON ImagePathListMaster.Id=Person.PersonImagePathListId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ImagePathListDetail AS ImagePathListDetail ON ImagePathListDetail.ImagePathListId=ImagePathListMaster.ImagePathListId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ImagePath AS ImagePath ON ImagePathListDetail.ImagePathId=ImagePath.Id`

Comment: **correct**

`SELECT COUNT(ImagePath.Id) AS ImageCount
FROM Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN ImagePathListMaster AS ImagePathListMaster ON ImagePathListMaster.Id=Person.PersonImagePathListId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ImagePathListDetail AS ImagePathListDetail ON ImagePathListDetail.ImagePathListId=Person.PersonImagePathListId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ImagePath AS ImagePath ON ImagePathListDetail.ImagePathId=ImagePath.Id`

Comment: @Jay, the differences is between how I join ImagePathListDetail . If I join it with `Person` table, the correct result is return while if I join it with `ImagePathListMaster`, the incorrect result is return. I don't know why it happen? Could you please tell me?

Comment: Unless ImagePathListMaster.Id = ImagePathListMaster.ImagePathListId, the two queries are not equivalent. I suspect the first join is supposed to be, "join ImagePathListMaster on ImagePathListMaster.ImagePathListId=Person.PersonImagePathListId". i.e. join on ImagePathListMaster.ImagePathListId, not ImagePathListMaster.id

Comment: BTW you don't need to say "join x as x". x will be called x unless you say otherwise. The redundant AS clauses make the query unnecessarily hard to read.

Comment: @Jay I need to change that. Thank for the advise anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your query and data as given should return the values you expect. Is this the actual schema, data, and query, or are you simplifying to make this post? I presume your real data does not include values like "test 1 C1", etc. Did you create a DB with these dummy field names and values to do this test, or are you saying that this is the equivalent of what you really have? If this isn't the actual stuff, it could well be that in simplifying you have left out the thing that's really causing the problem.

When I have a query that does not give the expected results, I try to drop out parts of the query to see where the problem is. Like try with only the first join and see if you get the expected results. If that works, add in the second join, etc. Leave out the GROUP BY and just dump all the records, so you can see the actual records and not just the count.

There are many possible sources of trouble. Maybe the data isn't what you think it is. Maybe one of the joins is using the wrong field. Maybe you're getting in trouble because you have different data types and a conversion is not giving the results you expect. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

If, as you say, your `Image.Id` column is declared `NOT NULL`, the only reason you should get a `COUNT(Image.Id)` of 0 for a `Person` would be if your `LEFT JOIN`s do not find any `Image`s for a given `Person`. In that case, `Image.Id` in your underlying results will be `NULL`, and therefore `COUNT(Image.id)` will be zero. This means that either:

- There's a `Person` who doesn't have any `ListMaster` entries.
- There's a `ListMaster` which doesn't have any `ListDetail` entries.
- There's a `ListDetail` entry which doesn't have any `Data` entries.

...or some combination of the above.

You should be able to quickly check which links are missing by adding `COUNT`s for the appropriate tables to your existing query:

```
SELECT  Person.Id AS PersonId,
        Person.Column1 AS PersonC1,
        Person.Column2 AS PersonC2, 

        -- NEXT TWO COUNTS ADDED FOR DEBUGGING
        COUNT(ListMaster.LId) AS ListMasterCount,
        COUNT(ListDetail.LId) AS ListDetailCount,

        COUNT(Image.Id) AS ImageCount
FROM Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN ListMaster ON Person.LId = ListMaster.LId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ListDetail ON ListDetail.LId = ListMaster.LId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data AS Image ON ListDetail.DataId = Image.Id
GROUP BY Person.Id,
         Person.Column1,
         Person.Column2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check if all your `Id, Column1, Column2` have image

```
SELECT  Person.Id AS PersonId,
        Person.Column1 AS PersonC1,
        Person.Column2 AS PersonC2, 
        ListMaster.*,
        ListDetail.*,
        Data.*
FROM Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN ListMaster ON Person.LId = ListMaster.LId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ListDetail ON ListDetail.LId = ListMaster.LId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data AS Image ON ListDetail.DataId = Image.Id
ORDER BY Person.Id,
         Person.Column1,
         Person.Column2
```